# How to add password to 2000 PDF files

Tags: batch-file, pdf

I need to add a password to 2000 PDF files (all PDF files in c:\reports).

Each file should have a unique password. At the same time, the file name and password should be saved in a CSV list.

Right now, I download `pdftk pro`. Here is the program:

```
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET prevsuff=::

for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2 " %%i in (c:\reports ?_*.pdf) do 
  set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
  set pass=!pass:~-8!
  pdftk *%%j.pdf cat output PDF\R_%%j.pdf owner_pw !pass!
  echo %%j R_%%j.pdf !pass! >> passwords.csv
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have access to a Windows system right now my current advice for you is this:

1. Change your code to address a different directory, say `c:\testreports`.
2. Create the directory `c:\testreports`.
3. Put not 2000, but only 5 different test PDF files into the new directory.
4. Make sure that the PDF testfile names are very simple at first (i.e. no spaces, no 'funny' characters).
5. Test your batch file.
6. If it runs successfully, add some more test PDFs, this time with filenames of similar 'weirdness' as may occur with your real 2000 PDFs.
7. Test again. Add 100 test PDF files. Test again.
8. If successful, turn your attention to the `c:\reports` directory. Don't forget to change your batch file accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is. You forgot the opening parenthesis in the `for` statement. Secondly, if your filename pattern contains spaces it should be quoted. So this should read:

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2 " %%i in ("c:\reports ?_*.pdf") do (
```

Finally, I don't understand why you refer to loop variables %%i and %%j if all you need is a single filename. What do you get if you `echo %%i, %%j` within the loop?

**edit:**
OK, I think I understand your intentions now. Look at this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

for %%F in ("c:\reports ?_*.pdf") do (
    set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
    set pass=!pass:~-8!
    pdftk "%%F" cat output "PDF\R_%%F" owner_pw !pass!
    echo %%F,R_%%F.pdf,!pass! >> passwords.csv    
 )
```

Changes:
- a simple FOR loop will loop over filenames
- filename pattern is quoted to protect the space(s) within
- loop variable in uppercase to make it visually outstanding
- the loop variable already ends with the .pdf extension
- I've put actual commas between the values for the CSV file ("comma separated values") to make it one
- no need for a `goto :EOF` at the end (unless some code follows this line)

**edit:**
I set up sample files, ran the batch file and got this output:

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

set filepattern="?_*.pdf"

REM cd /d C:\reports
cd /d d:\users\test

if exist passwords.csv del passwords.csv

for %%F in (%filepattern%) do (
    set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
    set pass=!pass:~-8!
    echo pdftk "%%~nxF" cat output "PDF\R_%%~nxF" owner_pw !pass!
    echo %%~dpnxF,R_%%~nxF.pdf,!pass! >> passwords.csv    
)
```

output:
    D:\Users\test>dir
    Datenträger in Laufwerk D: ist nano_D
    Volumeseriennummer: 2866-D343

```
Verzeichnis von D:\Users\test

18.04.2015  15:10    <DIR>          .
18.04.2015  15:10    <DIR>          ..
18.04.2015  14:43               830 12_def.pdf
18.04.2015  14:43               608 1_abc.pdf
18.04.2015  14:43               774 24_ghi.pdf
18.04.2015  14:43               663 2_def.pdf
18.04.2015  14:43               718 3_ghi.pdf
18.04.2015  15:10               165 passwords.csv
18.04.2015  15:09               434 renpdf.cmd
               7 Datei(en),          4.192 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 212.782.833.664 Bytes frei

D:\Users\test>renpdf
pdftk "1_abc.pdf" cat output "PDF\R_1_abc.pdf" owner_pw 48925581
pdftk "2_def.pdf" cat output "PDF\R_2_def.pdf" owner_pw 75025695
pdftk "3_ghi.pdf" cat output "PDF\R_3_ghi.pdf" owner_pw 34429279

D:\Users\test>type passwords.csv
D:\Users\test\1_abc.pdf,R_1_abc.pdf.pdf,48925581
D:\Users\test\2_def.pdf,R_2_def.pdf.pdf,75025695
D:\Users\test\3_ghi.pdf,R_3_ghi.pdf.pdf,34429279
```

Of course, as I didn't want to run the actual `pdftk` program I put an `echo` in front of the command line. Remove it to actually run that program.

Comment: I did the test. Here is the error message: %%F was unexpected at this time.
error: unable to find file
error: failed to open PDF file:%%f

Comment: What I want to do is to add unique password to 2000 pdfs. At the same time, the file name and password should be saved in a CSV list.  Thanks!

Comment: That error message says that there's a "%%f" in the code where a "%%F" should be. Please check spelling, the loop variable is case-sensitive. You may add a `echo %%F` right at the start of the loop to see which file is being processed.

Comment: here is the code:@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

for %%F in ("c:\reports ?_*.pdf") do (
    set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
    set pass=!pass:~-8!
    pdftk "%%F" cat output "PDF\R_%%F" owner_pw !pass!
    echo %%F,R_%%F.pdf,!pass! >> passwords.csv    
 )

Comment: After I typed this part:@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

for %%F in ("c:\reports ?_*.pdf") do (      The message shows %%F was unexpected at this time

Comment: Please see my edited answer, with sample input files and expected output. Please copy the (second) script 1:1 which IS working. Additionally, I've removed the reference to the folder `C:\reports` which was included in the filepattern but doesn't belong there.

Comment: Here is the exactly code:@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

set filepattern="?_*.pdf"

REM cd /d C:\reports
cd /d c:\results\test

if exist passwords.csv del passwords.csv

for %%F in (%filepattern%) do (
    set pass=!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!!random!
    set pass=!pass:~-8!
    pdftk "%%~nxF" cat output "PDF\R_%%~nxF" owner_pw !pass!
    echo %%~dpnxF,R_%%~nxF.pdf,!pass! >> passwords.csv    
)

Comment: I already installed pdftk pro and server. Is there anything wrong? The error messages are still same. (The message shows %%F was unexpected at this time.  error: unable to find file error: failed to open PDF file:%%~nxF